# esp8266 http client example

Tags: arduino, esp8266

Hi I have used **esp8266** module http client example and my code is exactly like the sample code.

This is a part of my code:

```
if (httpCode > 0) {
    if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) {
        String payload = http.getString();

        if(payload=="text") {
            digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        } else {
            digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        }
    }
}
```

I can't compare my variable with my text and the `LED_BUILTIN` is always on.  I am sure it can get the text of the http client page because I can send it to Arduino nano with `softwareserial`.

Comment: What do you get if you print the value of `payload`?

Comment: Try print payload with `Serial.println(payload);`

Answer (score 0):

Actually when i want to send it to arduino nano it gives me an error : no matching function for call to `HardwareSerial::write(String&)`

i could fix the error with this sample code

```
String mystring= http.getString();

  char* buf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*myString.length()+1);
  myString.toCharArray(buf, myString.length()+1);
  Serial.write(buf);
  free(buf);
```

but esp8266 module can't compare payload with my text

Answer (score 0):

If the LED was turned on, then the compare method was definitely work. Try to send different String from the server, your LED should be turned off. And also, when you got problems like this, try to print the "payload" to the serial monitor. At least, you could figure it out where the faulty is.

hope this help.